# v-model only updates when non-letter characters are entered on mobile browsers

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

When using `v-model` to update a data value it should update on character entered for any character.
This is true when tested on desktop browsers, however, when tested on mobile browsers (Chrome & Firefox on Android) the value only updates when non-letter characters are entered. Backspace also updates as expected.

Example Code:

```
<template>
  <input type="text" v-model="value" />
  <p>Value: {{ value }}</p>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      value: "",
    };
  },
};
</script>
```